# convert varchar array to date array-pl sql

Tags: arrays, oracle, date, plsql, varchar

I am trying to convert a a varchar array into a date array. Currently the date is being accessed from a Java class in the form of a String but it needs to be a date there. Therefore I need to convert the varchar array into a date array. I can only see questions here dealing with converting a string to a date format, which is not what I want. How different is it to convert a varchar array into a date array?

this is the variable which I need the procedure to convert.

```
P_IN_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE  IN P_DVP_CONSTS.T_VCHAR10ARRAY,
```

Comment: "but it needs to be an int there" - if it needs to be an int, why are you making it a date? Are the strings in the existing array already in a single fixed, reliable, format representing a date, e.g. all of them are YYYY-MM-DD or similar? Do you already have an array data type defined, and can you show the definition of that and the string array?

Comment: sorry that should read "date" instead of int, i will correct it. i have it defined as a varchar array which is ok on the sql but in order to be picked up by the java, i need a procedure to convert this to a date array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop around one array and use its contents to populate a second one; in this case with a `to_date()` call for each entry. As a simple demo:

```
create procedure convert_array(
  P_IN_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE IN P_DVP_CONSTS.T_VCHAR10ARRAY,
  P_OUT_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE OUT P_DVP_CONSTS.T_DATEARRAY
) as
begin
  P_OUT_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE := new P_DVP_CONSTS.T_DATEARRAY();
  P_OUT_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE.extend(P_IN_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE.count);
  for i in 1..P_IN_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE.count loop
    P_OUT_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE(i) :=
      to_date(P_IN_GRID_EFFECTIVE_DATE(i), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      -- or whatever format your strings are using
  end loop;
end convert_array;
/
```

And a quick test:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_strings P_DVP_CONSTS.T_VCHAR10ARRAY;
  l_dates P_DVP_CONSTS.T_DATEARRAY;
begin
  l_strings := P_DVP_CONSTS.T_VCHAR10ARRAY('2015-06-08', '2015-07-09',
    '2015-08-10');
  convert_array(l_strings, l_dates);
  dbms_output.put_line('Number of dates in array: ' || l_dates.count);
  for i in 1..l_dates.count loop
   dbms_output.put_line('Date ' || i
     || ': ' || to_char(l_dates(i), 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Number of dates in array: 3
Date 1: 08/06/2015
Date 2: 09/07/2015
Date 3: 10/08/2015
```

Answer (score 2):

Types and function:

```
create type tv as varray(5) of varchar2(15);
create type td as varray(5) of date;

create or replace function v2d (i_varchars in tv) 
  return td pipelined is
begin
  for i in 1..i_varchars.count
  loop
    pipe row (to_date(i_varchars(i), 'mm/dd/yyyy'));
  end loop;
end;
```

Test:

```
select * from table(v2d(tv('09/01/2010', '06/15/2015')));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
2010-01-01
2015-06-15
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using a package-level type, not schema-level, though; and wants to end up with the data in a (presumably also package-defined) array type. Neat anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I missed that package-level type, thanks.